# Copying A Sqlite File from Local Storage to an SD Card in WP8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

How can I copy my files from local storage to an sd card or known folders in WP8.1 for backup purposes?

I am using a folder picker to select the save location.

My code is:

```
Private Async Sub ButtonBackup_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim FolderPicker As New FolderPicker()
    FolderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary

    FolderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List
    FolderPicker.PickFolderAndContinue()

End Sub

Public Async Sub ContinueFolderPicker(ByVal args As FolderPickerContinuationEventArgs) Implements IFolderPickerContinuable.ContinueFolderPicker
    Dim folder As StorageFolder = args.Folder
    If folder IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including other sub-folder contents)
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder)
        'OutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked folder: " & folder.Name
    Else
        'OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled."
    End If
    Dim file As StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ContactsManager.sqlite")
    CopyFileToFolder(file, folder)

End Sub

Public Async Sub CopyFileToFolder(ByVal filetoCopy As StorageFile, ByVal folder As StorageFolder)
    Await filetoCopy.CopyAsync(folder)
End Sub
```

But the below line does not start:

```
Public Async Sub ContinueFolderPicker(ByVal args As FolderPickerContinuationEventArgs) Implements IFolderPickerContinuable.ContinueFolderPicker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved my question, below codes is corrent.

```
Private Async Sub ButtonBackup_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim SqliteStorageFile As StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ContactsManager.sqlite")

    Dim buffer() As Byte
    Dim stream As Stream = Await SqliteStorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()
    buffer = New Byte(stream.Length - 1) {}
    Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, CInt(stream.Length))

    Dim savePicker = New FileSavePicker()
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Backup File", New List(Of String)() From {".backup"})
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = SqliteStorageFile.Name

    Dim file = Await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()
    If file IsNot Nothing Then
        CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file)
        Await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer)
        CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file)
    End If
End Sub
```